# C#: Why is 0xFFFFFFFF a uint when it represents -1?

Tags: c#

I don't understand why C# considers the literal 0xFFFFFFFF as a uint when it also represents -1 for int types.

The following is code was entered into the Immediate Window shown here with the output:

```
int i = -1;
```

> -1

```
string s = i.ToString("x");
```

> "ffffffff"

```
int j = Convert.ToInt32(s, 16);
```

> -1

```
int k = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
int l = Convert.ToInt32(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

> OverflowException was unhandled: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.

Why can the string hex number be converted without problems but the literal only be converted using unchecked?

Comment: Read and learn about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: You cannot _convert_ it, but you can _cast_ it: if you write `(int)0xFFFFFFFF` you are forcing the bit pattern belonging to the number `0xFFFFFFFF`, that is, `FFFFFFFF`, to be interpreted as a signed integer (and will thus get -1 back).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is 0xFFFFFFFF a uint when it represents -1?

Because you're not writing the *bit pattern* when you write

```
i = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

you're writing a number by [C#'s rules for integer literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). With C#'s integer literals, to write a negative number we write a `-` followed by the magnitude of the number (e.g., `-1`), not the bit pattern for what we want. It's *really good* that we aren't expected to write the bit pattern, it would make it really awkward to write negative numbers. When I want -3, I don't want to have to write `0xFFFFFFFD`. :-) And I really don't want to have to vary the number of leading `F`s based on the size of the type (`0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD` for a `long` `-3`).

The rule for choosing the type of the literal is covered by the above link by saying:

> If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`.

`0xFFFFFFFF` doesn't fit in an `int`, which has a maximum positive value of `0x7FFFFFFF`, so the next in the list is `uint`, which it does fit in.

Comment: I was working on an answer with more or less the same content, referencing that link. I would quote the following line from it: "_If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong._" and since 4294967295 does not fit in a signed `int` it will use the second option.

Comment: @CompuChip Excellent quote, will do.

Answer (score 4):

`0xffffffff` is `4294967295` is an UInt32 that just happens to have a bit pattern equal to the Int32 `-1` due to the way negative numbers are represented on computers. Just because they have the same bit pattern, that doesn't mean 4294967295 = -1. They're completely different numbers so of course you can't just trivially convert between the two. You can force the reintepretation of the bit pattern by using an explicit cast to int: `(int)0xffffffff`.

Answer (score 1):

The [C# docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx) that the compiler will try to fit the number you provide in the smallest type that can fit it. That doc is a bit old, but it applies still. It always assumes that the number is positive.

As a fallback you can always coerce the type.

Answer (score 0):

The C# language rules state that 0xFFFFFFFF is an `unsigned` literal.

A C# signed `int` is 2's complement type. That scheme uses 0xFFFFFFFF to represent -1. (2's complement is a clever scheme since it doesn't have a signed zero).

For an unsigned int, 0xFFFFFFFF is the largest value it can take, and due to its size, it can't be converted to a signed `int`.